# How can I use ContourPlot to creat streamline: proper arrow orientation and correct domain?

Tags: plotting, graphics, fluid-dynamics

I get into trouble when I use `ContourPlot` to draw streamlines in a free surface flow domain.
[image]

This is [my data](http://www.wikiupload.com/PYG7KBKD0W6JIPN).The data are a little bit big, please be patient.
Here is my code:

```
Get["C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\...\\data.mx"]
```

Firstly, I plot the free surface, which is a function of x.

```
profile = Plot[mdfun[x, 6], {x, 0, 2*Sqrt[2] \[Pi]}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 2*Sqrt[2] \[Pi]}, {0, 2}},
ImageSize -> 400,Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black, Thick]},
FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, {1, "1.0"}, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8}, None},
{{0, {1, ""}, 2, {3, ""}, 4, {5, ""}, 6, {7, ""}, 8}, None}}]

hx = Derivative[1, 0][mdfun]; (*get the first derivative with respect to x*)
hxxx = Derivative[3, 0][mdfun];  (*get the third derivative with respect to x*)
scaledA[d_, B_, k_, e_, hx_, h_, hxxx_] := (-3*d*(1 + B*k) *hx )/((k + h + B*k*h)^3*e) - 3*1/e*hxxx - 3*1/e*hx;
A = scaledA[1, 1, 0.1, 0.05, hx[x, 6], mdfun[x, 6], hxxx[x, 6]]; (*calculate a term of stream function*)
scaled\[Phi][A_, z_, h_, B_, k_, hx_, e_, m_] := A*(z^3/6 - (h*z^2)/2) + m ((1 + B k)*k*hx*z^2)/((k + h + B k h)^2*e); (* stream function *)

sl = ContourPlot[scaled\[Phi][A, y, mdfun[x, 6], 1, 0.1, hx[x, 6], 0.05, 1] == Range[0.1, 1.3, 0.2],{x, 0, 2*Sqrt[2] \[Pi]}, {y, 0, mdfun[x, 6]}, ImageSize -> 400,ContourStyle -> {
Directive[Black, Thin],
Directive[Black, Thin],
Directive[Black, Thin],
Directive[Black, Thin],
Directive[Black, Thin],
Directive[Black, Thin],
Directive[Black, Thin]
}, Frame -> False (*,PerformanceGoal\[Rule]"Speed"*)] (*plot seven streamlines *)
```

**NOTE: `ContourPlot` takes about 60s on a common PC, you can uncomment `PerformanceGoal\[Rule]"Speed"` to speed up. Please be patient...The reason why I plot 7 streamlines is to show the different directions of the arrows drawn**

Then, I got the streamlines

[image]

If I use `RegionFunction` to explicitly specify the domain drawn.

```
sl2 = ContourPlot[scaled\[Phi][A, y, mdfun[x, 6], 1, 0.1, hx[x, 6], 0.05, 1] == Range[0.1, 1.3, 0.2],
{x, 0, 2*Sqrt[2] \[Pi]}, {y, 0, mdfun[x, 6]}, ImageSize -> 400, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 0 <= y <= mdfun[x, 6]],
ContourStyle -> {
Directive[Black, Thin],
Directive[Black, Thin],
Directive[Black, Thin],
Directive[Black, Thin],
Directive[Black, Thin],
Directive[Black, Thin],
Directive[Black, Thin]
}, Frame -> False(*,PerformanceGoal\[Rule]"Speed"*)]
```

I still get the same plot as above.

Then I add arrow for the streamlines

```
asl = sl /. Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{{0.02, 0.2}, {0.02, 0.4}, {0.02, 0.6}, {0.02, 0.85}}], Arrow[x]}
```

And I got the following plot

[image]

Last, I combine the profile and streamlines.

```
Show[profile, asl]
```

[image]

> Here I have four questions:

(1) How can I specify the upper limit in a free surface problem? Here I employed  `{y, 0, mdfun[x, 6]}`;

(2) Is there any method to find all the representative or distinctive streamlines instead of assign different values to `ContourPlot` every time;

(3) Frankly speaking, I am not sure whether my streamline is correct or has the completed range. Because I drew them by restricting the y-range by `{y, 0, mdfun[x, 6]}` in the first code, in addition, by `RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 0 <= y <= mdfun[x, 6]]` in the second code `sl2`. I really do not understand the difference between them in my case.

(4)**This question has been solved by @ bbgodfrey**. As you can see, the orientation of the arrows of the streamlines is different from each other. I have tried to change the sign of `0.02` in `Arrowheads`, but I still can not get the same orientation anyway, say towards the right. Can any one tell me how can I manipulate the arrow individually for each streamline?

Thank you for your patience!

Comment: If all you're trying to do is to draw arrows in the contour lines, why did you post your full problem? Just make up a fake and simple `CountourPlot[]` and re-ask without all the burden

Comment: Here's a nice fake example for y'all: `sl = ContourPlot[Cos[x] + 1/2 y^2, {x, -2 π, 2 π}, {y, -π, π}, Contours -> 5, AspectRatio -> Automatic, ContourStyle -> Directive[Black, Opacity[1]], ContourShading -> None]`

Comment: Anyway, I do think that this is a misfeature of Mathematica. Contour lines of a scalar function *can* be assigned a consistent orientation based on which side of the line has the larger function value, and it would be nice if Mathematica automatically respected that orientation. In the meantime, I hope someone posts a nice workaround.

Comment: @ belisarius. Please see the update, the questions are related to my full problem. Thanks :)

Comment: @ Rahul, Thank you for your nice example. I just acquire the use of `Contours->5` :). BTW, what is your mean by "based on which side of the line has the larger function value"? As we known, for streamline or the contour lines in `ContourPlot`, the value of each curve is a constant.

Comment: If you include a space after `@` then the user will not be pinged. You should ping like so @Ixy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although `InputForm` for these plots is enormous, due to the `InterpolatingFunction`s used,

```
Cases[asl, GraphicsComplex[x__]]
```

allows the data associated with `Arrow` and `Arrowheads` to be isolated.  Doing so shows that the data for most contours runs right to left, but for a few from left to right.

A work-around is as follows.  Determine the `Position` of the `Line` Commands in `sl`.

```
Position[sl, Line[x_], Infinity]
(*{{1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4},
{1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 5}, {1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 6}, {1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 7}, {1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 8}}*)
```

The first entry is associated with the bottom curve, the next entry with the second curve, etc.  Use this information to reverse the order of points in the desired lines.  Here, I assume that arrow heads in lines 3 and 6 are to be reversed.  So, insert

```
Part[sl, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1] = Reverse[sl[[1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1]]];
Part[sl, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 7, 1] = Reverse[sl[[1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 7, 1]]];
```

just before the line creating `asl` to produce

[image: Second plot with arrows heads aligned]

as desired.  Inelegant but effective.

**Addendum**

The process described above can be automated using a command structurally similar to that used by Michael E2.  Instead of reversing the data of curves on a case by case basis, replace the `asl` command by

```
asl = sl /. gc : GraphicsComplex[p_, __] :> (gc /. 
  Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{{0.02, 0.2}, {0.02, 0.4}, {0.02, 0.6}, {0.02, 0.85}}], 
  Arrow[If[p[[First@x, 1]] > p[[Last@x, 1]], x, Reverse[x]]]})
```

Comment: Could you pls tell me what is the meaning of ` 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1` in `Reverse[sl[[1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1]]]`, especially, the last `1`. Thank you!

Comment: `1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4` is the `Position` of `Line[x_]`, and the extra `1` at the end gives the position of `x_` itself, which is what we want to `Reverse`.  However, it is better to use the expression in *Addendum*, which is more flexible.

Comment: @ bbgodfrey. Yes, Thank you! Let me take some time to understand it. By the way, your caution about the accuracy of hxxx gives me a idea to eliminate the 3rd derivative in my function by manipulate my original equation. Thus, this problem should be solved by a mathematical trick which is out of the range of `ContourPlot`.

Answer (score 7):

Along the lines of [Rahul's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/484/rahul) comment:

Two possible methods:

1. If the function `f` is differentiable, the compare the directions of the `Grad` of `f` with the (2D) [`Cross`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cross.html) of the direction of the line.
2. Use the [`Cross`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cross.html) of the direction of the line to determine which side of the contour has the higher value of `f` by comparing the value of `f` on contour with a point on the side (toward which `Cross` points).

Toy example (I worked this out before seeing Rahul's comments):

```
f[x_, y_] := y - x^4/100 + x^2/10;
sl = ContourPlot[
  f[x, y] == Range[-1, 0.4, 0.2], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -2, 1}, 
  ImageSize -> 400, ContourStyle -> Directive[Black(*,Thin*)], 
  Frame -> False (*,
  PerformanceGoal\[Rule]"Speed"*)] (*plot seven streamlines*)

asl = sl /. 
  Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[{{0.02, 0.2}, {0.02, 0.4}, {0.02, 0.6}, {0.02, 0.85}}], Arrow[x]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Method 1:

```
asl = sl /. 
  gc : GraphicsComplex[p_, __] :> (gc /. 
     Line[ll_] :> {Arrowheads[{{0.02, 0.2}, {0.02, 0.4}, {0.02, 0.6}, {0.02, 0.85}}],
       Arrow[If[
         Dot[
           Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}] /. Thread[{x, y} -> p[[First@ll]]],
           Cross[First@Differences[p[[ll[[;; 2]]]]]]
           ] > 0,
         Reverse[ll], ll]]})
```

Method 2:

```
scale = 0.1; (* controls how far to step to the side *)
asl = sl /. 
  gc : GraphicsComplex[p_, __] :> (gc /. 
     Line[ll_] :> {Arrowheads[{{0.02, 0.2}, {0.02, 0.4}, {0.02, 0.6}, {0.02, 0.85}}],
       Arrow[If[
         Less @@ (f[x, y] /. {Thread[{x, y} -> p[[ll[[2]]]]],
             Thread[{x, y} -> 
               p[[First@ll]] + scale Cross[First@Differences[p[[ll[[;; 2]]]]]]
              ]}),
         Reverse[ll], ll]]})
```

Output:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The orientation can be reverse by reversing the comparison in the `If` statement.

Comment: @ Michael E2, Thank you very much!!